# run javascript from a string

Tags: javascript, string

Hi im tying to run javascript from a string/array **without eval** if possible. here is kinda what I want.

```
code = ["document.write('hello')", "function(){}"];
code.run[1];
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Why don't you want to use eval?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can execute it as a function.

Like this

```
function yourNewEval(){
    var code = ["document.write('hello');", "function(){}"];
    var F = new Function(code[0]);
    return(F());
}
yourNewEval();
```

Answer copied from Stefan's answer.

A lot of creative answers in [How can I execute Javascript stored as a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/939326/how-can-i-execute-javascript-stored-as-a-string)

Answer (score 5):

<strike>The only way to run javascript from a string is to use `eval()`.</strike>
Correction: Aside from `eval("codeString");`, `new Function("codeString")();` will execute your code, too. The disadvantage of this is that your code will have to be interpreted when you when you call `new Function(...)`, compared to optimisations the browser may use when pre-defining the code, like the example below.
So, `eval("codeString");` and `new Function("codeString")();` are possible, but bad ideas.

A better option would be to store functions in a array, like this:

```
function foo(){
    document.write('hello');
}
function bar(){
    return 1+2;
}

var code = [   foo,
               function(){
                   alert("Hi there!");
               },
               bar
           ];
code[0](); // writes "hello" to the document.
code[1](); // alerts "Hi there!"
code[2](); // returns 3.
```