# How to change a string expression to an resulted integer?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I execute Javascript stored as a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/939326/how-can-i-execute-javascript-stored-as-a-string)

Let us suppose this:

```
var a = 10;
var b = 20;
var exp = "a+b";
var result = ?;
```

Change the above expression which is string to give result in integer. Variable a is 10. Variable b is 20. Variable exp is a string containing the expression. Change that string expression to add variable a and variable b and store it in Variable result.

How can I do that with Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using Javascript `eval()` function you can do above thing.

Like:

```
var a = 10;
var b = 20;
var exp = "a+b";
var result = eval(exp);
```

Comment: `eval` works, but avoid it unless absolutely necessary: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Don.27t_use_eval.21

Comment: yeah, I know buddy that it is to be avoided :D but thanks :)