# How to execute function calls that passed in JS function as string without eval?

Tags: javascript, string, execute

I think this is kind of unusual, but this is what I came to.
I have a .net application that generates html + js page.
I have a thing called **Unit** that is kind of assembly of different html elements and has artificial events onlaod and onunload.

```
function DisplayableUnit(content, onload_js, onunload_js)
{
    this.onload_js = onload_js; //different functions calls like "f1(); f2();"
    this.onunload_js = onunload_js;
    this.content = content; //string of html tags
}

function loadUnitTo(elem_id, unit)
{
    var elem = document.getElementById(elem_id);

    if (elem)
        elem.innerHTML = unit.content;

    if (unit.onload_js)
        ;//how to execute it?
}
```

Many sites says that eval is bad and unsafe thing. But is that the only choice?
I need pure JS solution without any third party things.

Comment: eval is not bad at all, you can't parse a script without it. it's doing stupid crap with eval that's the problem. if your site has no user-generated unmoderated input, then eval is without risk. at any rate, Function() is no better, and in fact, eval() can be made safe in "use strict", but "Function" cannot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can execute it as a function like this:

```
var theInstructions = "alert('Hello World'); var x = 100",
    F=new Function (theInstructions);

return(F());
```

Copied from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/939326/execute-javascript-code-stored-as-a-string) stackoverflow thread ;)

Comment: +1 Never knew this! Is there any big difference between this and `eval` other than the fact that this can be called multiple times?

Comment: To me it looks like you are just creating a function using the function constructor, so it should be much faster than eval (not sure)