# Execute JS code from string input

Tags: javascript, function, parsing

Is there any way to do the following?

```
var value = foo;
execute("value = 'bar'");
console.log(value) // returns 'bar'

function execute(jsCodeString) {
    // execute js code
}
```

Comment: The other question is, "Are you sure that you have to execute your code this way?".  I think `window["value"] = 'bar'` would accomplish the same thing.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Where is the string actually coming from (a literal doesn't make sense)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to use "eval" for this.

```
function execute(jsCodeString) {
    eval(jsCodeString)
}
```

See this: [Execute JavaScript code stored as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/939326/execute-javascript-code-stored-as-a-string)

Comment: This answer and Chris's answer were equally good, and I accepted this one at random. +1 for both answers as they are clear and link to documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Use eval()

```
eval("value = 'bar'");
```

Anyway, I suggest you to read about the pros and cons of using eval()
[When is JavaScript's eval() not evil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197769/when-is-javascripts-eval-not-evil)