# Execute JScript code stored as a string and pass arguments

Tags: eval, jscript, wsh

So I've read [Execute JavaScript code stored as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/939326/1798187) and looked at this simple [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/939343/1798187).

My question, what if the `JScript` code, stored in the string, expects arguments? how to I pass it?

#### First try:

```
var jsStr = "WScript.Echo(WScript.Arguments[0]);";
eval(jsStr);
```

#### Second try:

```
var F = new Function(jsStr);
F.call(this,'test str');
```

But this poor attempt failed.

#### Note:

Let's assume the I have no control on `jsStr` value. So basically, reformatting it is out of the question at this moment.

Comment: I would imagine you would have to do a replace... ie `jsStr.Replace("{0}", myParameter);`.  A JS string.Format function will do just fine.

Comment: How would you know which arguments it expects? I cannot see any parameters in your `jsStr`.

Comment: why do you want this? if you want help, include the full code, what is WScript?

Comment: @micnic this script is independent, meaning, is not run as a web application but run using `Windows Script Host`. Reference: [Wscript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/at5ydy31%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)

Comment: @Bergi Assume that I would save `jsStr` to a file and execute the file with command line arguments. that is what I want to achieve without having to save it to a file.

Comment: Don't know, what is `WScript`, but try `(new Function('WScript.Echo(arguments[0])'))('test str')`

Comment: Your original code works in the context of a jsfiddle using `arguments[0]` as @Johan says - the issue is more that `WScript.Arguments` won't work with function arguments. The question should probably be re-tagged with WScript and reworded to describe calling WScript.Arguments when the script is in a string

Comment: @idanshmu, does your environment (WScript) does not offer you an `require` in the same way like Node.JS does to include and execute files? eval is evil!

Comment: @idanshmu: But if you `eval` some js code, it *does* have access to your global `Wscript.Arguments`? If you want to execute it as a separate script, it seems you need to create a file with the code and [`Run`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky(v=vs.84).aspx) or [`Exec`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ateytk4a(v=vs.84).aspx) it.

Comment: @Bergi But creating a file is exactly what I'm trying to avoid. It seems odd to me that I need to create a file just because `jsStr` expect command line arguments. is this the only case where `eval` is not the solution for? if so, How do I solve it without creating a file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is caused by the []. WScript.Arguments is an object (provided by the script host runtime), but not an array. To access its elements, you have to use (), i.e. call its Item() function. Evidence:

```
var jsStr;
jsStr = "WScript.Echo('a', WScript.Arguments(0));"; eval(jsStr);
jsStr = "WScript.Echo('b', WScript.Arguments.Item(0));"; eval(jsStr);

var expr;
expr = "typeof WScript.Arguments"; WScript.Echo(0, expr, eval(expr));
expr = "typeof WScript.Arguments(0)"; WScript.Echo(1, expr, eval(expr));
expr = "typeof WScript.Arguments[0]"; WScript.Echo(2, expr, eval(expr));
```

output:

```
cscript 27250366.js pipapo
a pipapo
b pipapo
0 typeof WScript.Arguments object
1 typeof WScript.Arguments(0) string
2 typeof WScript.Arguments[0] undefined
```