# How to execute JS statement from a string?

Tags: javascript, variables

I wanna basically execute a statement stored in a var. For example, I have this,

```
var statement = "alert('Hi!')";
```

How can I make JS execute the statement stored inside the var statement? Thanks a lot guys.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/939326/execute-javascript-code-stored-as-a-string

Comment: For what reason are you trying to do this?

Comment: I wanna make a JSshell for myself. @LeonardoDelfino

Comment: see which one is better eval() or new Function, http://www.2ality.com/2014/01/eval.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do it, but it's not recommended

```
var statement = "alert('Hi!')";
eval(statement)
```

Comment: It does not even work. Any other solution?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) constructor

```
var func = new Function("alert('Hi!')")
func(); // call it
```

You could `eval` but this method is comparatively safer.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for [eval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp)
    `var test = "alert('toto')";`
    `eval(test);`

Answer (score 1):

you can use `eval("my script")`.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use `eval()` like this:

```
var statement = 'alert('Hi!');";
eval(statement);
```

eval is a dangerous thing though and should be used with caution.