# Parse a function as Json string to Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, eval

I have a string like this:

```
var jsontext = 'function(prog) {return ' + path + ';}';
```

and i want to parse this into javascript.

How can i do this?

Thomas

Comment: Use `eval`. But i don't recommend it

Comment: That's not [JSON](http://json.org/). And you should be careful with what you're asking for.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Execute JavaScript code stored as a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/939326/execute-javascript-code-stored-as-a-string)

Answer (score 0):

This is not JSON, but Javascript as a text string that you want to evaluate.

You will want to use the `eval(jsontext)` function, but I would highly discourage this as it is a very risky function as it executes the script with the privileges of the caller.  It is also a bad idea for performance reasons.  If at all possible, define your function in the script itself instead of as a string!

See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval).

Comment: My problem is that the next function use this function as parameter.

Comment: var tester = buildFilter(node, selector);     selector is the function with the path.

Comment: Can't you just pass the `path` variable to the next function and create the function within the next function, so you don't have to pass through code?  If you can post these two functions I will try to find a solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here the complete code. The eval function doesn't work and i need a workaround.

function buildRecursiveFilter(filterDef) {
        var filterFuncs = [];

```
    // Rekursiv für alle nodes Regex filter funktionen definieren
    naw.visitNode(filterDef, function(node, path) {

        if (typeof node !== "object") {
          var selector = eval("(function(TBM) { return " + path.toUpperCase() + "; })") ;
            var tester = buildRegexFilter(node, selector);         
          filterFuncs.push(tester);
        }
    }, "tbm");

    if (filterFuncs.length === 0) return noFilter;

    // wende alle test funktionen auf tbm an und liefere die UND Verknüpfung
    return function(tbm) {
        return _.reduce(
            _.map(filterFuncs, function(f) { return f(tbm); }),
            function(akku, res) { return akku && res; });
    };
}

function buildRegexFilter(filterDef, fieldSelector) {
    fieldSelector = fieldSelector || (function(tbm) { return tbm.WP; });
    var def = filterDef;
    if (typeof (def) === 'string') {
        def = def.split(',');
    }
    var filters = [].concat(def); // Array erzwingen
    filters = _.map(filters, function(s) { return $.trim(s); });
    var expression = '(' + filters.join('|') + ')';
    var rx = expression !== '(.*)' ? new RegExp(expression) : undefined;

    return function (tbm) {
        return rx.test(fieldSelector(tbm));
    };
}
```

Thomas

Comment: ich mein das nicht böse aber du solltest wirklich javascript lernen.

Comment: Lach, bin doch dabei. Das Script ist auch nicht von mir. Ich versuch nur grad ne Lösung für das Fehlverhalten zu finden

Comment: na dann ist ja gut. falls du den kennst der das geschrieben hat dann hau ihm auf die finger.
hau dir das mal rein: http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/javascript
und das hier: http://books.google.de/books/about/Pro_JavaScript_Design_Patterns.html?id=za3vlnlWxb0C&redir_esc=y

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution for my problem. I have removed the line with eval and have it replaced with this:

```
var fn = "function(tbm) { return " + path.toUpperCase() + "; }";
var selector = new Function("return (" + fn + ")")();
```

Thomas