# Executing javascript functions stored as string using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there any way to inject JavaScript code stored in a string in AngularJS controllers dynamically?

```
var dynamicJS = "function DoSomething(value){var x = 1+1  return 2;}"
```

I have to dynamically inject the above function into my AngularJS controller and have it be called on selection change of drop-down, the values of which are bound to the AngularJS controller. The reason is the JavaScript function would vary based on my each row of data which I have based on my configuration at an application level. I am aware we can make use of `$eval` but would like to get some better approaches, if any exist.

Can anyone give me any idea on this?

<sub>*Note: I am using AngularJS v1.4.5*</sub>

Comment: Why are you storing a function as a string in the first place?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/939326/execute-javascript-code-stored-as-a-string

Comment: Per my requirement I have to do some data population or some validations based on the data which I have. In some case I dont need to execute any but for some other case I may need to execute it with the configured JS functions for that data. the JS function is not consistent and I can execute it based on configured for the specific data per my requirement. make sense ?.

Comment: This is a **very dangerous** thing to do;  it is **extremely easy** to create attack vectors into your app by modifying these strings.

Comment: it is intranet application and not going to outer world. no issues on this for this req. thank you though.

Comment: Is there a fixed number of functions that would be used? Could those be defined with the main angular controller code (or in a provider) and utilized based on a certain attribute of the markup or data?

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple ways to achieve this.

- ## Function object

  Create a [Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function), passing the one argument (i.e. *value*) and *functionBody* as parameters:

  ```
  var dynamicJS = "var x = 1+1;  return 2;"
  var DoSomething = new Function("value", dynamicJS );
  ```
- ## eval()

  While arguably more dangerous<sup>[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4599946/1575353)</sup>, [eval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) can be used.

  ```
  var dynamicJS = "function DoSomething(value){var x = 1+1  return 2;}"\
  eval(dynamicJS);
  ```

  Because you mentioned in a comment

  > "*it is intranet application and not going to outer world. no issues on this for this req.*"

  this would likely be fine but please read the section below.

  ### *Caution*

  From the [this section of the MDN documentation about eval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Don't_use_eval_needlessly!):

  > #### Don't use eval needlessly!
  >
  > <sub>`eval()` is a dangerous function, which executes the code it's passed with the privileges of the caller. If you run `eval()` with a string that could be affected by a malicious party, you may end up running malicious code on the user's machine with the permissions of your webpage / extension. More importantly, third party code can see the scope in which `eval()` was invoked, which can lead to possible attacks in ways to which the similar [`Function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) is not susceptible.</sub>
  >
  > <sub>`eval()` is also generally slower than the alternatives, since it has to 
  >   invoke the JS interpreter, while many other constructs are optimized by modern JS engines.</sub>
  >
  > <sub>There are safer (and faster!) alternatives to `eval()` for common use-cases.</sub>
  >   <sup>[2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Don't_use_eval_needlessly!)</sup>

See a demonstration of these techniques utilized below. Click on the buttons corresponding to each technique to see the output on the console.

```js
var dynamicJS = "function DoSomething(value){var x = 1+1;  return 2;}"
var functionBody = "var x = 1+1;  return 2;";
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  document.getElementById('eval').addEventListener('click', function() {
    eval(dynamicJS);
    console.log('DoSomething(3) -> ',DoSomething(3));
  });
  document.getElementById('function').addEventListener('click', function() {
    var dynamicFunction = new Function("value", functionBody);
    console.log('dynamic function(3) ->',dynamicFunction(3));
  });
});
```

```html
<button id="eval">click to eval</button>
<button id="function">click to use Function</button>
```

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>https://stackoverflow.com/a/4599946/1575353</sub>

<sup>2</sup><sub>https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Don't_use_eval_needlessly!</sub>

Comment: Eval can be very Evil! Take care.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Don%27t_use_eval_needlessly!

Comment: Yep - agreed. I have incorporated that info.

Answer (score 2):

I would believe the easier way will be to parse the String and then use the function constructor.

Something like this:

```
var DoSomething = new Function('value', 'var x = 1+1  return 2');
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try something like:

```
function myFunc(obj){
    var param = obj.hasOwnProperty('param') ? obj.param : undefined;
    console.log(param);
}

var funcString = "myFunc({ param: 'something' });",
    Construct = new Function(funcString);

Construct();
```

Haven't tested it to be honest ... but this way you avoid `eval()`.

more info on [Function object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function)