# JQuery - Extract Javascript from var

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a method that return a string like this:
[image]

I need to extract that javascipt variable, any suggestions ?

Comment: Well, you could use `eval` ...but it's dangerous! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/939326/execute-javascript-code-stored-as-a-string

Answer (score 0):

You would need to extract right side of equal sign, and then eval

for example:

```js
var test = "var Admin = ['test1', 'test2']"
var Admin = eval(test.split("=")[1]);
console.log(Admin);
```