# Convert string into function in Javascript or JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In JS or Jquery, is it possible to convert a string into a function, and run it ?

Something like this :

```
var s = 'var n = 0; n++; alert(n)';
convertStringToFunction(s); // this would show an alert with the content '1';
```

My actual case is not this, it's just a simplified example. What i'm trying to achieve is a way to generate a JS code in runtime and execute it.

Thanks !

Comment: maybe you are trying to achieve [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/939326/execute-javascript-code-stored-as-a-string)?

Comment: Like `eval(s)`?

Comment: Exactly. Thanks !

Comment: Sounds like a potential debugging nightmare.