# Adding JavaScript contained in a variable as a script element

Tags: javascript, html, variables, createelement

The powers that be have asked me to look into this and as much as I think it's not possible I want to be sure before going back to them. Don't ask me why they want this haha

They want to be able to use JavaScript that is defined in a variable. Let me explain...

Let's say you have this variable:

```
var testvar = "function dan() { alert('hello world'); }";
```

They want to be able to call `dan()` and have an alert popup in the web page. Something like this doesn't appear to be useable (of course).

```
var importjs = document.createElement('script');
importjs.src = testvar;
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(importjs);
```

Any ideas or jargon I can use to explain why it's not doable. I believe it's essentially a cross origin issue. Our solution requires users to install software, which uses web sockets. This software performs a file GET for the JS and we then want to use the JS in the browser.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/939326/execute-javascript-code-stored-as-a-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set the `innerHTML` of the script element to your String. The `src` of a `script` element should only be used to load an external script.

```js
var testvar = "function dan() { alert('hello world'); }";
var importjs = document.createElement('script');
importjs.innerHTML = testvar;
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(importjs);
dan();
```

Comment: This seems to be better than the eval() answer by. In your opinion is your answer a better practice?

Comment: @DanJamesPalmer `eval` should be avoided in most cases (it is both dangerous and slow).