# Data bound v-if dynamic condition

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I was wondering if it's possible to have a data binded v-if directive, I have an array of objects representing nav links or buttons (for login , logout ...) each of this objects has a v-if property where I define the v-if condition as a string.

From my laravel backend:

```
$globals['socialLinks'] = 
        [
            [ 'title' => 'facebook', 'v-if' => '$app.auth', 'icon' => 'fab fa-facebook-f', 'url' => config('app.facebook'), 'image' => '/img/social/facebook-alt-white.svg' ],
        ];
```

In my template (I transform this into json and pass it to my vue component template):

```
<div class="LAYOUTfooter9_row_container">
            <a class="LAYOUTfooter9_social_image_container" :href="social.url" v-for="(social,index) in $app.globals.socialLinks" v-if="[social.v-if]" :key="index+'S'">
                <img class="LAYOUTfooter9_social_image" :src="social.image">
            </a>
        </div>
```

Comment: I guess you could try to eval(), although it's not a recommendable practice. What triggers my curiosity here is... is your front-end responsible to know what to display? Isn't it easier to filter your results on the back-end?

Answer (score 0):

[Execute JavaScript code stored as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/939326/execute-javascript-code-stored-as-a-string) can be **dangerous**. Think twice if you really need it...

```html
<a class="LAYOUTfooter9_social_image_container" :href="social.url" v-for="(social,index) in $app.globals.socialLinks" v-if="evaluateCondition(social.v-if)" :key="index+'S'">
```

```js
methods: {
  evaluateCondition(condition) {
    return eval(condition)
  }
}
```

Your conditions have to be an expression and will be executing in the context of Vue instance so instead of `$app.auth` you need to use `this.$app.auth`