# Can I execute script from json file

Tags: javascript

Can I execute script from json file?
For example:

```
helloworld.json
{
"script" : "console.log('helloworld');"
}
```

I want to run the script in the json file in my html or js file.

Comment: You might need to provide more details on your use case and surrounding code. You might also want to check `eval`.

Comment: You could try using `eval()`, but this is highly discouraged due to a security risk! https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval

Comment: you can find solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/939326/execute-javascript-code-stored-as-a-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Point eval to the string to execute it as code

```
var json = {"script":"console.log('helloworld');"}
eval(json["script"])
```

> Also see [Execute JavaScript code stored as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/939326/execute-javascript-code-stored-as-a-string)

Comment: Executing JavaScript from a string is an enormous security risk. It is far too easy for a bad actor to run arbitrary code when you use eval(). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Never_use_eval!

Comment: Of course! You are just executing code that could have been edited by anyone. A use case may be a single one time test or for experimental reasons. Doesn't mean it should be used in production software.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to:

1. [Load your json file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19706046/how-to-read-an-external-local-json-file-in-javascript/45035939)
2. Execute the script using [`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)

Whether that's a good idea or not though depends on your specific use case.

Comment: Executing JavaScript from a string is an enormous security risk. It is far too easy for a bad actor to run arbitrary code when you use eval(). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Never_use_eval!