# Coding HTML Files for an output in an html file

Tags: javascript, html

How do I build a site that allows me to code html in it. Where I can type code in a textarea and get the entire output for that code beside the textarea in which I code?

Comment: this question will help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/939326/execute-javascript-code-stored-as-a-string

Answer (score 2):

You can use JavaScript; create an id for the button and a div to display the text when the button is clicked:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>background</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    
        #text{
            display:none;
        }
    
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="text">
        My Name Is Anurag.
    </div>
        
    <button id="click">click</button>
        
    <script type="text/javascript">

        document.getElementById("click").onclick= function(){
            var text= document.getElementById("text")
            if(text.style.display=="none"){
                text.style.display="block";
            }else{
                text.style.display="none";
            }
        }

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I want to type in a `<textarea>`, click a button, and =have whatever I typed in the textarea to be copiede to the DIV on the click of a button. But thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

```js
document.getElementById("click").onclick = function() {
  var textDiv = document.getElementById("text")
  var textarea = document.getElementById("textarea");

  textDiv.innerText = textarea.value;
}
```

```html
<div id="text">
  Here comes text from textarea
</div>
<textarea id="textarea"></textarea>
<button id="click">click</button>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I've already tried this, it works perfectly, but  was wondering if there was a way to allow me to use the <body> and <head> tags in this. I'm not if you can do that?

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question. but I put the code above on stackblitz so you can see it with **<body>** and **<head>** tags. https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-thbwsx?file=index.html