# Execute JavaScript code stored as a string with <Script> tag

Tags: javascript

This post is more related with the question asked here.
[Execute JavaScript code stored as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/939326/execute-javascript-code-stored-as-a-string)

but my problem seems little different here.

When I am trying to execute code like this, it errors out `unexpected token '<'`

```
setTimeout('<script>console.log("some string")</script>', 1);
```

Facing same issue with `new Function( '<script>console.log("some string")</script>' )`

Comment: Probably you have HTML with a script tag (with JavaScript inside), not JavaScript.

Comment: yes, of course you get that error. Your title suggests that you already know that this is not valid JS syntax. You'll need to remove the `script` tag and use `eval`. Is the string you want to "run" hard-coded or does it change?

Comment: Try this `setTimeout(function() { console.log("some string"); }, 1);`

Comment: Actually, this JS code is coming from a code snippet string that can have <script> tag included. I have used settimeout which works fine when there is no script tag added in string but the same errors out when it fount tags included.

Answer (score 0):

```
    let incomingString='<script>console.log("some string")</script>';
    let f = new Function(incomingString.replace("<script>","").replace("</script>",""));
    f();
```

Thiw code on Node outputs: some string
but it can't run on snippet