# execute function having its content as a div's text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to execute what is inside `wrap` div
here is my try - without success

```js
$('button').on('click', function(){
  window[$('#wrap')[0].text()];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='wrap'>console.log('323');</div>
<button>CLICK</button>
```

Comment: `eval()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/939343/2820150) help?

Comment: I found somewhere that `eval` is deprecated

Comment: @provance where?

Comment: @noviceinDotNet - tried without `[0]` - doesn't work

Comment: @CodeSpirit - here - `https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-call-function-from-it-name-stored-in-a-string-using-javascript/

Comment: @provance try do eval($('#wrap').text())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `Function` instead.

The refactored code will look like that

```js
$('button').on('click', Function($('#wrap').text()));
```

You can try the example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/eyhqj9u6/1/)

And you can learn more about `Function` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function)

Comment: interesting thanks a lot, solved

Comment: No problem mate have fun coding :)